# How to get a file from the assets folder and put it into hierarchy by script in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm kinda new to Unity and I want to get an image from my assets folder and put it into the hierarchy and I need to do it repeatedly.

I found out about Resources.Load but apparently it takes a file from another path and uploads it to a folder called resources in the assets folder, as I understand... I need some clues about what methods and classes can be useful to ease this process. Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: In the editor or at runtime?

Comment: Resources.Load() is function that will load the specified file. If it's an Image you could have an Image Gameobject in the Scene and reference that inside the script. After this you can assign it to that Gameobject's image component.

Comment: @hijinxbassist runtime.

Comment: > "Resources.Load but apparently it takes a file from another path and uploads it to a folder called resources in the assets folder" - No. It loads given resource from disk to RAM and allows to use it. So there is two ways of getting things onto the scene at runtime: no matter waht type of object you want (GameObject, ScriptableObject or maybe Sprite), you need to reference it under [SerializeField] in the calling object (that will be on scene already), or you just call `var playerObject = Resources.Load<GameObject>("Prefabs/Player")` when `Player` prefab is at `Resources/Prefabs` folder.